# Will re-assignment of a huge list/array cause a memory leak?

Tags: python, numpy

If I created a huge list/array, say

```
a=range(1000000000)
or
a=numpy.ones(100000000)
```

then I re-assign a as:

```
a=1
```

After this re-assignment, will the previous huge list or array be automatically deleted, or, there is a potential memory eat-up if its inside a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will garbage collect as normal, it might take a little bit to be reaped.  But it will not memory leak (or it should not, if it does then there's a bug in the numpy module which should be reported.)

Comment: +1 Correct and doesn't fall into the trap of assuming reference counting. Case in point: `numpypy` is still far from complete, but the sample code would already work under PyPy (and hopefully, so will real programs in the near future).

Comment: Doesn't al least cpython cache free integers and floats? See: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm

Comment: @RolandSmith Yes, but numpy arrays don't actually contain millions of Python objects around (that's why they are as efficent as they are, rather than regular lists with go faster stripes).